# Calling member functions of immutable classes

Tags: class, d, immutability, member-functions

```
immutable class Foo
{
    void bar()
    {
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto x = new Foo();
    x.bar();
    // Error: function test.Foo.bar () immutable is not callable
    //         using argument types ()
}
```

What do I have to change in the program so that `x.bar()` compiles? Does `x` have the wrong type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug. `x` is inferred to have the type `Foo`, which although is an immutable class, it is treated as if a mutable variable, which caused `x.bar()` to fail because `bar()` is an immutable method.

A workaround is to provide an empty immutable constructor function,

```
immutable class Foo
{
    void bar()
    {
    }

    immutable this() {}    // <---
}
```

which caused the `new Foo()` expression to return an `immutable(Foo)`.

Comment: Are you seriously telling me I found a bug in D within the first hour of using it? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes, I was a bit underwhelmed when I actually started using it, too. It has *lots* of bugs, unfortunately, not all of which can be still fixed, since they're afraid of code breakage. (If you search the newsgroups you'll see I've gotten *really* annoyed at const/immutable in the past.) The fact that it's *physical* const-ness in D -- unlike in C++, which has *logical* const, which might confuse you for a while -- has lots of implications and imposes lots of restrictions on you that wouldn't happen in C++. Good luck with D.. it's pretty good in some ways, but not in others.

Comment: @FredOverflow yup, D's current implementation is full of bugs.  I would say it's going to take 2-4 years for it to be production quality, but 2-3 years ago I thought by now it would be at that point.

Comment: I would argue that it is not strictly a bug because nowhere is specified that immutable classes will get an implicitly defined default constructor for immutable objects...

Comment: @Mehrdad and Arlen - no offense, but you guys are using an unstable branch of D - D2 - so bugs are expected. If you want stable D, unfortunately you will have to stick to the old D1. I know, it is hard because D2 has some good and radical changes (including the abovementioned immutable)...

Comment: @DejanLekic: Yes, I'm aware. I was just stating the facts. I never said the bugs weren't expected, or that D2 was considered stable. In fact, I was, just like you, pointing out that it isn't stable. :)

Comment: @DejanLekic. The bug is that a `Foo` variable is not immutable even if the class is marked as `immutable`.